# Sencha Touch Chart: Scroll bars with in chart panel and setting bar width

Tags: sencha-charts

I am working on a mobile application and using sencha touch charts. By default horizontal bar chart is fitting  exactly into screen. If there are more number of bars,then bars are appearing very thin and looking odd. I want to fix bar width to have uniform look and feel irrespective of number of bars being displayed. No matter even user need to scroll down to see entire chart. I have tried below option in series configuration, but it did not work.

```
style : {
        size : 30
        }
```

Please help me.

Thanks,
Nag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code in my interactions to render the labels, it's working fine

```
 {
 type: 'panzoom',
  showOverflowArrows: false,
//axes: ['bottom'],
axes: {
      bottom: false,
      left: {
      startZoom: 2
      }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

am able to change the bar width by setting barWidth option in touchcharts-debug.js by refering to the following link

http://docs.sencha.com/touch-charts/1-0/source/Bar.html

but the axis labels are not rendering properly labels are fitting into screen